# Адаптивное меню JS

Tags: javascript, адаптивная-верстка

Есть адаптивное меню, которое должно открывать при клике на определенном разрешении, но при обновлении страницы изначально меню показывается открытым.

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.nav-list');
menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');
hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');

function toggleMenu() {
  hamburger.classList.toggle('hamburger-active');
  menu.classList.toggle('nav-open');
}
hamburger.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);

menuItem.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    hamburger.classList.toggle('hamburger-active');
    menu.classList.toggle('nav-open');
  })
})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вопрос написан двусмысленно, в стиле "казнить нельзя помиловать". я не понял, что у вас получилось, а что нет. может оформить код в виде фрагмента "JavaScript/HTML/CSS"? так и другие посмотрят что у вас за гамбургер.

Comment: Необходимый функционал: меню должно открываться по клику на гамбургер. Имеем: меню на странице открыто изначально, меню выплывшее, сверху крестик.Хотелось бы, чтобы по дефолту было наоборот

Comment: обычно меню открыто на большом разрешении, а на маленьком оно превращается в гамбургер. если у вас есть исходный код меню, то поищите @media запрос и установите большее разрешение. если вы не хотите разбираться в чужом компоненте или его код минифицирован, то возьмите другое меню, их десятки в интернете и ютюбе (https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/MWEJEWG)